# A convex optimization problem, to maximize $C^{T} \Sigma \theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms

Consider this problem: $\max \limits_{C \in \mathbb{R}^{m*1},\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n*1}} C^{T}\Sigma \theta$ ,s.t. $C^{T}C=1$ and $\theta^{T}H\theta=1$

where,$C \in \mathbb{R}^{m*1},\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m*n},\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n*1},H \in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$,H is symmetric.

Before giving your advise , please take a look at my try:

Consider $f(C,\theta)=C^{T}\Sigma \theta -\lambda (C^{T}C-1)-\mu (\theta^{T}\theta-1)$,

we have,

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}=\Sigma \theta -2\lambda C=0$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\Sigma C-\mu (H^{T}+H)\theta=0$

putting $C^{T}C=1$,$\theta^{T}H\theta=1$.

Hence, $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}C^{T}\Sigma \theta$ ,$\mu=\frac{1}{2}\theta^{T}\Sigma^{T}C$.

Then

$\Sigma \theta=C^{T}\Sigma \theta C$,$\Sigma^{T}C=\frac{1}{2}\theta^{T}\Sigma{T}C(H+H^{T})$.

But I don't know how to make $C$,$\theta$ out from the above two equations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know the problem is convex? How do you know a $\max$ exists? Is $H$ positive definite?

Comment: First, this problem is nonconvex, since you have nonlinear equality constraints. Also, I believe you are missing a transpose on $\Sigma$ in your expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$. Aside from these points, can you explain your approach? It looks to me like you are forming the Lagrangian and using the KKT conditions to solve for possible minima of the problem? Remember that KKT conditions are not sufficient for optimality since your problem is nonconvex, and furthermore there may be many solutions to the KKT conditions in this case.

Comment: Forgive me. H is positive definite. I missed this condition last night.

Comment: I made a mistake.This problem is not convex for the nonlinear multiplication in the objective function.But I am thinking we can still get a maximum even if the objective function is nonlinear.We should note that the two original constraints are both elliptical, so that the multiplication in the objective function has a bound.If we can figure out those possible minima, then we compare those and we can probably get one maximum.

Comment: Sorry for those typing mistakes in my try.$f(C,\theta)$ should be $C^{T}\Sigma \theta-\lambda (C^{T}C-1)-\mu (\theta ^{T}H\theta -1)$ .